# Stripe Payouts to Bank Account in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to automise money transfer from website to the user's bank account. What is the proper way to do it?

I tried to create bank account fist with JS call first:

```
  Stripe.bankAccount.createToken({
    country: 'US',
    currency: 'USD',
    routing_number: routing_number,
    account_number: account_number,
    account_holder_name: account_holder_name,
    account_holder_type: account_holder_type
  }, function(status, response) {
    token_input.val(response.id);
    form.submit();
  });
```

I receive response from Stipe:

```
{id: "btok_8JTQwnYQQAEAlF", object: "token", bank_account: …}
```

On server side I tried to use token ()

```
Stripe::Transfer.create(
    :amount => 400,
    :currency => "usd",
    :destination => params['bank_account_token'],
    :description => "Payout"
  )
```

However I get Stripe reponse is:

```
No such destination: btok_8JThh75QpdnB4m
```

What is the way to transfer funds from Stripe to any US Bank Account?

Comment: Paying out funds to your users has a lot of implications and you can't just transfer some funds to their bank account like this. You need to use Stripe Connect: https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Comment: @koopajah can you maybe briefly describe what should be done in order to send a simple payout?

Comment: Well there's no way to send a "simple payout". You need to change your integration completely here. You need a standalone or managed account for each recipient of the funds in your account and then you need to charge on their behalf so that Stripe knows at the time of the charge, who the funds are for: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees I'd recommend taking a few hours and reading through the entire Connect docs here.